How to get rid of blank space around a QLabel in a QVBoxLayout() in PyQt5
I have a simple window that has a QLabel as a header and a QFrame that contains some input boxes.
I tried to make a layout for them, but I noticed that the QFrame always aligns to the bottom even when I put setAlignment as Qt.AlignTop. As it turns out, the QLabel border reveals that it has so many unused space (maybe because QVBoxLayout() forces them to have equal heights?)
It's weird that somehow this is a problem suddenly even though other layouts I've made align just fine as I want it.
I've tried adding adjustSize() and all other alignment ways I could think of but it still does not work
So, how do I get rid of this extra spaces so that the QFrame can sit directly on the bottom of the text of the QLabel?
Image :


Please provide a [mre], but you may just need to add the bottom widget with the stretch=1 argument of addWidget().

Note that setting the alignment in layouts only ensures that the related item is aligned within the item cell the layout assigns to it (using its size hint), it doesn't "push everything" in some direction (and it shouldn't). Also, this isn't peculiar of QVBoxLayout, but all QLayout descendants; specifically, box and grid layouts will always try to assign equal spaces to all its items, unless stretch factors are explicitly set (or set in the children's size policies). I strongly suggest you to read the whole layout managers documentation and related classes.

Thanks for the insight, I solved it by setting a SizePolicy that is minimal for the horizontal part.

Although not wrong, there's no need to change the size policy. As already written, it's enough to just add a stretch factor argument when calling addWidget() for the bottom part.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
